# Split partition dataset into training and test (The training data has 200 examples of each class)

Tags: python, machine-learning, split, scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have a 5-class data. There are approximately 1000, 1200, 1500, 1900, 2000 samples in each class. I would like to have 200 examples of each class in training data. The other samples will be the test data. That is, the training data will consist [200, 200, 200, 200, 200] samples in each class, test data will consist of [800, 1000, 1300, 1700, 1800] samples in each class.

How can we do this in Python? Are there any predefined methods/packages to do this in Python?

Another Examples

`train_test_split(data, labels, train_size=`**0.0042**`)
Label Number  Total Samples Train Samples Test Samples
     1           6631           33          6598 
     2          18649           89         18560 
     3           2099            6          2093 
     4           3064           11          3053 
     5           1345            5          1340 
     6           5029           26          5003 
     7           1330            3          1327 
     8           3682           21          3661 
     9            947            6           941 
Total           42776          200         42576`

`train_test_split(data, labels, train_size=`**200**`)
Label Number  Total Samples Train Samples Test Samples
     1           6631           33          6598 
     2           18649          89         18560 
     3           2099            6          2093 
     4           3064           11          3053 
     5           1345            5          1340 
     6           5029           26          5003 
     7           1330            3          1327 
     8           3682           21          3661 
     9            947            6           941 
 Total           42776          200         42576`

So, I want it to be like this:

`Label Number  Total Samples Train Samples Test Samples
     1           6631           200          6431
     2           18649          200         18449
     3           2099           200          1899
     4           3064           200          2864
     5           1345           200          1145
     6           5029           200          4829
     7           1330           200          1130
     8           3682           200          3482
     9            947           200           747
 Total           42776          1800        40976`

Comment: What have you done till now?

Comment: I googled, but I could not find an effective solution. The `train_size` parameter in the `train_test_split` function is not a solution. If `int` is, the percentage is calculated automatically.

Comment: What do you mean by percentage is calculated automatically if int?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `train_size` parameter of `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` to an integer value which represents an absolute number of train samples, 200, in your case. If it's a float, it should lie between 0.0 to 1.0 to represent the proportion of the training sample you want to consider. For example, 0.8 means 80%.

Comment: If the parameter `train_size` is 200, then the number of elements in each class of training data is [26,32,39,50,53] respectively. The total number of samples in the training data is 200. I dont want this. Each class consists of 200 samples, so you have a total of 1000 samples in training data.

Comment: So what if you put 1000 as `train_size`, it will not be 200 for all but around 200, is it really important that it's equal?

Comment: I'm sorry I can not tell you my problem. I have added a detailed example to the question. I hope it becomes explanatory.

Comment: Your problem is clearer now. I can only think of first creating out 5 separate DataFrames, each DataFrame containing sample of 1 class/label. Apply train_test_split on each one of them with train_size = 200. That will give you 5 training sets and 5 test sets which you can combine pythonically to get a single training and test set.